# Make custom "Build Customizations"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012, and performing OpenCV programming in C++ environment.
I wish to add opencv settings in "Build Customizations" option which is obtained on right-clicking a project in VS2012. The settings is intended to include additional Include directories, and library file names for linking.
Kindly guide me. I have already tried searching over the internet for this problem, and the instructions I found online were not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Such settings would be managed via a Property Sheet (`.vsprops` file) nowadays. It sounds like you should write a custom `OpenCV.vsprops` property sheet.

Comment: Actually I am aware that the file type is .vsprops .  I would further like to know how to create a custom one.